# Difference between 2 if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

Hey I was wondering why this first piece of code is different than the second, the first piece of code takes in True and outputs 1 while the second one correctly outputs "nope". To me both if statements should produce the same output.

1.

```
def distance_from_zero(Number):
    if type(Number) == int or float:
        return abs(Number)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```

2.

```
def distance_from_zero(Number):
    if type(Number) == int or type(Number) == float:
        return abs(Number)
    else:
        return "Nope"
```

Comment: Note that the canonical way to do this in Python is `if isinstance(Number, (int, float))`

Comment: The if statement is evaluated like so (For 1 and 2):
1 -> `if (type(number) == int) OR float`, or 
2 -> `if (type(number) == int) OR (type(number) == float)`

The first is checking for the truthfulness of `float`.